# Get a list of all figures plotted using Matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook for data analysis, where I need to plot several figures one after the other, in **seperate cells**

for example, lets say I have 15 figures, as below:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(...)
plt.barh(...)
```

*...*

```
fig2 = plt.figure(...)
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.barh(...)

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.barh(...)
```

*...*

```
fig15 = plt.figure(...) 
plt.barh(...)
```

How do I obtain a list of these figure names? like so:

```
[fig1, fig2, ...., fig15]
```

P.S: I have already tried `fig_nums = plt.get_fignums()` - which returns an empty list :(

Answer (score 0):

`plt.get_fignums()` returns nothing since you're not creating figures, not directly at least. `plt.barh()` returns a container. If you want to keep track of your figures, use

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.barh(...)
...
```

Then `plt.get_fignums()` returns a list of figure numbers created with `plt.figure()`.

If this is not what you want, the easiest way would be to store all `fig#` in a `list`

```
figures = []
fig1 = plt.barh(...)
figures.append(fig1)
...
``
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was thinking about the `ax` method as well, but was confused how to use that in case of a figure having subplots (I have updated the example in my question)

Comment: You can always retrieve the figure by `plt.figure()`. As such, you can build a list like `figures = [plt.figure(i) for i in plt.get_fignums()]`. @Kunal

Answer (score 0):

I have also found this workaround that seems to help in jupyter:

```
fig_list = [f for f in globals() if 'Figure' in str(type(globals()[f]))]
print(fig_list)
```